# Issues with apps requiring online integration

Tags: webapps

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying it out for the first time (Quantal Quetzal). I was trying out the google contacts lens and Nuvola Player (for google play music) and I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to load page
>
> Problem occurred while loading the URL
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&client_id=666398043069.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> Cannot resolve hostname (accounts.google.com)

Could you help me out with this please?